# What is the registration process after entering Russia visa-free initially as a tourist and then for staying with a friend?

Tags: russia, visa-free-entry

Its a simple ask, how work the registration to visa free travel to russia?

1) Do I need a hotel?

2) 
   2.1- Can I stay at a friend’s house without an invite letter?
   2.2- If yes, how does this work? Do I need to register in a hotel first? Or with a Travel agency? And then re-register when I move to my friend’s house?

Can anyone tell me something about visa-free rules?

Edit: I am a Brazilian citizen and I’ll be entering by air.

Comment: The answer depends upon your citizenship, and what mode of transport (plane? ferry? cruise ship? train?) you'll enter Russia.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137324/i-need-help-with-visa-free-in-russia-and-questions-about-immigration-card-regi

Comment: @David I will arrive in airport, and my citizenship is brazilian, you know something?

Comment: 1) No. 2.1) Yes. Russo-Brazilian visa waiver agreement says that visas are necessary for short visits with the following purposes: commerce, work, activities related to religion, charities, studies, training and science. If the purpose of your trip is private, it is not on that list, so you don't need a visa, and thus you don't need an invitation. 2.2) Your friend must register your stay, and that is done relatively easily by filling out a form at a post office.

Comment: @ach Please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: @ach You have experience about this? It's really my first concrete answer about this, so i need be sure because i searched much and didn't found nothing till now

Comment: Please do not add ‘solved’ or anything similar to the title. Rather [mark the best answer as accepted by clicking the little tick mark below the voting buttons on its left](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Real Russia, a reputable Russia-focused travel agency, if you're coming to Russia when invited by a friend, you just need to go the local UFMS office to get it registered. See [here](https://realrussia.co.uk/Visas/Russian/Registration#q9).

Comment: I will not go invited, i am going as a tourist, but i will stay in a private house. I need book a hotel before go to russia and then there register that i am at a private house?

Comment: I’m not an expert but if Russia is anything like other countries where staying in a private home requires permission from the authorities, you will almost certainly need to book a hotel and then apply to change your immigration status from visa-free (tourist) to private. The permission may not be forthcoming or may take some time; while you wait you’ll have to remain in the hotel, so I suggest you apply for the correct visa from the start. You could also contact the Russian embassy in Brazil to check what’s required.

Comment: UFMS. FMS  stands for Federal Migrational Service, in exactly that order. :) Except for this service does probably exist no more as its functions and facilities have been transferred back to the Ministry of Internal Affairs.

Comment: No, you don't need to book a hotel. Whoever owns the house you're staying at has to register you with the Ministry of Internal Affairs.

Comment: @SandyBridge A visa-free citizen dont need a invite letter to a private travel? as another person told commenting at my ask?

Comment: The OP is a Brazilian citizen, which has a visa free regime with Russia. Invites are only required to get visas. @ViníciusOliveiraGouveia